# How can I fix my terminal error showing trackback(most recent call)

Tags: terminal, trackback

Whenever I open my terminal Instead of showing the user it shows an error

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/powerline-shell", line 5, in 
from powerline_shell import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'powerline_shell'

Comment: Did you install powerline-shell beforehand? Try "pip install powerline-shell", this could fix your problem.

Comment: Also, look at this solution on AskUbuntu: [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1247863/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-powerline-shell)